# Remove specific subfolders with findstr via a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write up a batch script removing the subfolders (e.g.c:\temp\root\students\students23435) which has a name starting with the name of its (parent) folder (e.g.c:\temp\root\students).

The folders in bold as shown below should be removed:

> c:\temp\root\students
>
> **c:\temp\root\students\students23435**
>
> **c:\temp\root\students\students9875**
>
> c:\temp\root\students\1234
>
> c:\temp\root\teachers
>
> **c:\temp\root\teachers\teachers12345**
>
> **c:\temp\root\teachers\teachers898**

```
@echo off
rem pushd "c:\temp\root\"
for /F "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir /a:d-s-h /b ^| findstr /B /I /C:"students" /C:"teachers"') do ( 
  echo Removing Directory "%%I" 
  rmdir /s /q "%%I" )
rem popd
```

Could you please help me fix this code?

Thank you very much.

Have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First loop over all folders. Then for each folder `%%p`within, if there is a folder named like `%%p\%%p*`, delete it and all files and folders below (otherwise the folder cannot be removed).

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%p in ('dir /b /ad') do (
    for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /b /ad "%%p\%%p"* 2^>nul') do echo rmdir /s /q "%%p\%%d"
)
```

For testing, I have masked the `rmdir` command with a `echo`, so that matching folders will only be printed. Remove the `echo` to really delete folders.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /d %%A in (C:\Symbols\*) Do (
    For /F "Delims=" %%B In ('@Dir /b /ad %%A') Do @Echo RD /s C:\symbols\%%B
    )
```

Is one way.

Comment: Didn't understand. 

What's the replacement of "@Dir"?

How can I skip deleting the parent folders (e.g. c:\temp\root\teachers, c:\temp\root\students) ?

Comment: Change `C:\Symbols` to `c:\temp\root` and run it.